# Recommend a free, universal database browser?

Tags: database

This can be community wiki.

I'm looking for a simple, multi-platform, free database browser (ODBC,etc).  This is for those times when I want to interface with a database, and just need a simple way to quickly see what the heck is in it.  Doesn't need to support any vendor-specific features.

Too much junk out there and I don't want to play with these things all day.  What do you use?

Answer (score 13):

I like [SqlDbx](http://www.sqldbx.com) - the personal edition is free.  It supports most of the major databases, and the built in intellisense is useful for queries.

Comment: Well, it's Windows only, but I do like that there's no installation.  Just used it and it worked like a charm.  +1

Answer (score 7):

Dbvisualizer has a free version http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/download/

Comment: dbvis does not support ODBC out of the box.  You have to get paid JDBC to ODBC bridge software.